# pandas DataFrame line plot does not work when there are missing values but scatter plot works fine

Tags: python, pandas, plot

In Python pandas DataFrame, when a column does not have value for every index value, the line plot will be partially or entirely missing, but the scatter plot will be just fine. Is there a way to plot the line plot correctly? I am on 0.24.2 version of pandas.

Note this question is not a duplicate of some other similar questions, since I don't want to fillna or interpolate the missing values since that is not what I want to show. I just want the missing to stay missing, and a straight line connect every two closest non-missing dots (which is the normal behavior one would expect for line plots).

Thanks in advance.

Creating an example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index = range(1,21,2), columns=['val1'])
df1.val1=np.random.rand(10)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = range(2,22,2), columns=['val2'])
df2.val2=np.random.rand(10)

df=df1.append(df2, sort='False').sort_index()
df
```

[image]

A scatter plot looks just as what I expect:

```
df.plot(style='.')
```

[image]

A line plot, on the contrary, does not work:

```
df.plot(style='-')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there is a difference between lines and markers in terms of styles as they are concepts at different dimension (1D and 2D).

- There will be a line if there are two consecutive non-na points.
- There will be a marker, however, as long as there is a non-na point.
  I.e., the point can be isolated from the other points.

This behavior not only applies to pandas plot, but also to most software in general (e.g., Excel).

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop the NaN values on-the-fly. So your data frame will remain the same it will take just not-NaN values and indexes for plotting. When you use pandas plot, in default it will use indexes as the x-axis. Even if you drop the NaN values, indexes will remain the same so the plot will be as you desire. It will not squeeze the x-axis because of the dropping NaN values.

```
df.plot()
df.iloc[:,0].dropna().plot()
df.iloc[:,1].dropna().plot()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas will not plot a line with `NaN` values. There is no way around this as far as I know. Either use a different plot type or fill your `NaN` values in an acceptable manner.

It isn't clear what you would expect a line plot to even look like here. You have 0 `(x,y)` pairs to plot.